# Python Function Encapsulation (to avoid accidental invocations without proper context)

Tags: python, encapsulation, modularity

I'm cobbling together a small, internal app, dumping it from my head in a "bottom-up" way.

As such, once I have discovered that a function I'm writing works, I'd like to make it a "helper" function and prevent myself from coming back in an hour or a year and writing code that invokes it in a way I didn't meant to invoke it.

In Java, I could just make a class, make my "helper" functions private static methods, and put the code I "mean to" invoke them from into a public static method.

**What's the pythonic way to avoid stepping on your own toes as I've described?**

Here's a really simple example function I don't want to let myself call from "just anywhere":

*(For example, maybe for editability I'd like to keep all functions that need the "simple_salesforce" module close together but don't want to expose functions like getAFreshContactList() to invocation outside of nicely exception-handled code controlling the flow of login, determining whether a fresh Contact list is even needed, logout, etc.)*

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
def getAFreshContactList(sfSession):
    if isinstance(sfSession, Salesforce):
        return sfSession.query("SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact LIMIT 2")['records']
```

Thank you!

Comment: Use a leading underscore to make it *private-by-convention*? Exclude it from the `__all__` exports from that script?

Comment: The Python convention for "private" things it to name them with a single leading underscore (e.g. `_getAFreshContactList`). Such functions and variables won't be listed by `dir()` or `help()`, nor with they be imported by `from module import *` (though you probably shouldn't be doing that kind of imports anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the function to a separate helper module. Do not  import the module using * notation and the function calling convention will behave exactly like that of a Java static function. For example:

**my_helper.py:**

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
def getAFreshContactList(sfSession):
    if isinstance(sfSession, Salesforce):
        return sfSession.query("SELECT Id, Name, Email FROM Contact LIMIT 2")['records']
```

**my_program.py**

```
import my_helper
def someFunction:
    my_helper.getAFreshContactList(None)
```

Virtually the entire point of [Python namespaces](http://www.python-course.eu/namespaces.php) is exactly to create a separation between names that serve different purposes.

While python *convention* allows you to prepend an underscore to a module attribute to prevent it from appearing in docs and star imports, [there is no such thing as truly private in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private):

> “Private” instance variables that cannot be accessed except from inside an object don’t exist in Python. However, there is a convention that is followed by most Python code: a name prefixed with an underscore (e.g. _spam) should be treated as a non-public part of the API (whether it is a function, a method or a data member). It should be considered an implementation detail and subject to change without notice.

In Java you would have to use reflection to call the privately declared methods of a class, but in Python there is never anything to stop you from invoking `my_helper._myPrivateFunction()` directly besides convention. Prepending an underscore to a function or any other attribute should just serve to remind you to be extra careful when you use it outside the module.

Comment: Thanks, and I see how that makes it act like a static function.  However, what I won't get is making such a function act more like a "private" static function.

What you explained seems to me more like the "public static function" I said I would expose in a Java class than the "private static functions" I said I wanted to hide from the main program.

Comment: I have done my best to address your concern here. Unfortunately, there is no such thing as "private" in Python.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  Definitely my biggest adjustment of getting into this language!

Comment: Sorry for the delay - at first, I didn't select it as an answer because I didn't feel it directly addressed my concerns, but then I saw you edited it ... but I got busy.  Will do!